# git commit does not find path on linux windows subsystem (WSL)

Tags: git, sublimetext3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to type `git commit` and get to sublime text editor on my [WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) by configuring my `.gitconfig` file in this way:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w"

git config --global core.editor "'/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe' -w"
```

But both paths do not work. I'm not sure what's wrong, since I get the error message that the system cannot find the path.

On `.bashrc` I have an alias for sublime (subl) `alias subl='"/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe"'` that works fine though. Not sure how to prompt sublime text by committing on WSL.

When submitting `git commit` the editor pops up but i cannot save the commit message with following error.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the WSL Git?  If so, what does `git config -l` show (as a code block)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using WSL Git . core.editor='/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe' -n -w
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process

Comment: Does running the exact command after the equals sign in the `core.editor` line (including the quotes) with a space and a file name added to it cause the editor to pop up?  Does the prompt fail to return until you've quit the editor?

Comment: hi yes the editor pops up but i cannot save, i just added some more clarifications on the question on this regard. Please check it out the image I uploaded. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Same issue here

Comment: hey no, as I recently switched to Vscode from Sublime